# Stop CDATA tags from being output-escaped when writing to XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, cdata

We're creating a system outputting some data to an XML schema. Some of the fields in this schema need their formatting preserved, as it will be parsed by the end system into potentially a Word doc layout. To do this we're using `<![CDATA[Some formatted text]]>` tags inside of the App.Config file, then putting that into an appropriate property field in a xsd.exe generated class from our schema. Ideally the formatting wouldn't be out problem, but unfortunately thats just how the system is going.

The App.Config section looks as follows:

```
<header>
<![CDATA[Some sample formatted data]]>
</header>
```

The data assignment looks as follows:

```
HeaderSection header = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("header") as HeaderSection;
report.header = "<[CDATA[" + header.Header + "]]>";
```

Finally, the Xml output is handled as follows:

```
xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(report));
fs = new FileStream (reportLocation, FileMode.Create);
xs.Serialize(fs, report);
fs.Flush();
fs.Close();
```

This should in theory produce in the final Xml a  section that has information with CDATA tags around it. However, the angled brackets are being converted into `&lt;` and `&gt;`

I've looked at ways of disabling Outout Escaping, but so far can only find references to XSLT sheets. I've also tried `@"<[CDATA["` with the strings, but again no luck.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: To get code formatting (which allows `<` etc) inline in a paragraph, you can use backquotes (as in my edit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing markup with content.

When you assign the string `"<![CDATA[ ... ]]>"` to the value, you are saying that is the *content* that you wish to put in there. The `XmlSerializer` does not, and indeed should not, attempt to infer any markup semantics from this content, and simply escapes it according to the normal rules.

If you want CDATA *markup* in there, then you need to explicitly instruct the serializer to do so. Some examples of how to do this are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379888/how-do-you-serialize-a-string-as-cdata-using-xmlserializer).

Comment: This does seem the most likely solution. It just seems strange that I can't take the CDATA from the App.Config and transfer it straight over. I can see where you're coming from with the markup / content issue though.

The Xsd class was autogenerated, so a little trickier than normal to assign a node as [XmlIgnore] (the reccomended method in the link you provided), but hopefully it should work ok. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing

```
report.header = "<[CDATA[" + header.Header + "]]>";
```

to

```
report.header = "<![CDATA[" + header.Header + "]]>";
```