# The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type ''X' failed because no type converter can convert between these types

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm stumped with this one and your help would be most appreicated.

I get the error:

> The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type
>   'DataPortal.Models.EntityClasses.FeedbackComment' failed because no
>   type converter can convert between these types

The `ModelState.IsValid` is failing on the `FeedbackComment.Comment` property

Any ideas?

```
public class FeedbackComment : IFeedbackComment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set;}

    public int FeedbackId { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Comment")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }

    public string CommentBy { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Methods

```
//
    // GET: /FeedbackComment/Create

    public virtual ActionResult Create(int feedbackId)
    {
        var comment = new FeedbackComment {FeedbackId = feedbackId, CommentBy = User.Identity.Name, CommentDate = DateTime.Now};
        return View(comment);
    } 

    //
    // POST: /FeedbackComment/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Create(FeedbackComment comment)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            _feedbackCommentRepository.Add(comment);

            return RedirectToAction(MVC.Feedback.Details(comment.FeedbackId));
        }

        return View(comment);
    }
```

And the view

```
@model DataPortal.Models.EntityClasses.FeedbackComment
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create Comment";
}
<h2>Create Comment</h2>
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Feedback Comment</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comment, new{@class = "TextEditor"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment)
    </div>


    @Html.HiddenFor(model=> model.CommentDate)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=> model.CommentBy)       
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=> model.FeedbackId)

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Comment Details", MVC.Feedback.Details(Model.FeedbackId))
</div>
```

Comment: Try changing the FeedbackComment parameter name in your POST action. Also you should set CommentBy and CommentDate in your POST action rather than using a hidden field

Comment: Thank you very much for your secondary tip.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The problem is the name of your action parameter:

```
public virtual ActionResult Create(FeedbackComment comment)
```

It's called `comment`. But your `FeedbackComment` also has a property called `Comment` of type string. So the default model binder gets crazy. Just rename one of the two to avoid the conflict.

For example the following will fix your issue:

```
public virtual ActionResult Create(FeedbackComment model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _feedbackCommentRepository.Add(model);
        return RedirectToAction(MVC.Feedback.Details(model.FeedbackId));
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Ah, of course, makes complete sense when you think about it. Always thought you'd be safe from those kind of shenanigans as c# is case sensitive. Thank you very much.

Comment: Incredible amounts of time wasted with this error.  +1 for you and thanks!

Comment: This is so difficult to debug it should be a compiler warning or something. The chances that the model variable is going to relate to the content and have the same name as of it's parameters is extremely high.

Comment: WOW! I was working on a problem similar to this for the last 3 hours.  Thank you so much!

Comment: "gets crazy" indeed!

Comment: I had an issue like this as well, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same name for the parameter on the GET method

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(int OSSB)
```

.. and a property from Faturamento model, that was used on the POST method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Faturamento model)
```

Just like this..

```
public class Faturamento {
        [Column("ID_OSSB")]
        public virtual int ID_OSSB { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ID_OSSB")]
        public virtual OSSB OSSB { get; set; }
        ...
}
```

What solved for me was changing the GET parameter name:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(int IDOSSB)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but the cause was different from the accepted answer. Adding a custom `ModelBinder` fixed it for me.

I created a `CData` class as described here

[How do you serialize a string as CDATA using XmlSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379888/how-do-you-serialize-a-string-as-cdata-using-xmlserializer) (it's the last answer unless it got voted up because it's a great solution)

I serialize my ViewModel to XML. When I set a type in a property in my ViewModel to `CData`, it will automatically be serialized to a CData section and deserialized to a `CData` field. (which is great!)

When I do a post action in my view I want to keep some fields in my ViewModel so they are added as `Html.HiddenFor` in the form.

When a submit is done, an error occurs (the one in the title). The model binder tries to bind a string field to a CData field which fails.

A custom model binder for the `CData` type fixes this

```
public class CDataModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        return new CData(result.AttemptedValue);
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
 ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(CData), new CDataModelBinder());
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was writing a model class name in Html Helper class. which was getting it failed as it was expecting a `System.String` datatype and I was passing a custom class name.