# Writing CDATA in ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Im using the setting:

```
formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

The class i try to serailize is quite simple:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        CDATA = "<![CDATA[<link>MyLink</link>]]>"

    [XmlText]
    public string CDATA { get; set; }
}
```

I want this to be serialized into something like:

```
<MyClass>
     <![CDATA[<link>MyLink</link>]]>
</MyClass>
```

But instead get:

```
<MyClass>
     &lt;![CDATA[&lt;!link&gt;MyLink&lt;!/link&gt;]]>
</MyClass>
```

So how can i prevent this? Or is there a better way using the ASP.NET WebApi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379888/how-do-you-serialize-a-string-as-cdata-using-xmlserializer) will do it:

```
[XmlIgnore] public string Content { get; set; }

[XmlText]
public XmlNode[] CDataContent {
    get {
        return new XmlNode[] {
            new XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(Content)
        };
    }
    set { Content = value[0].Value; }
}
```

This works with a regular `XmlSerializer` object, so I'd guess it works in WebAPI as well.