# XmlSerializer - node containing text + xml + text

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I have a node that can contain either text or xml, text + xml or text + xml + text. The first two cases i have solved using

```
    [XmlAnyElement]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public XmlElement[] TextNodes { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string InnerText { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Text 
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Format("{0}{1}", InnerText, TextNodes.Aggregate(String.Empty, (current, documentNode) => current + documentNode.OuterXml));
        }
    }
```

However, the last case where there is text after the xml I cant find a solution for.

**XML**

```
<node>
 somtext <p>moretext</p> even more text
</node>
```

my code will give output in Text as:

```
sometext <p>moretext</p>
```

I need:

```
sometext <p>moretext</p> even more text
```

Comment: Side note: What if your node will contain incorrect syntax xml? It will make your main xml incorrect.

Comment: True, but then everything will fail at a much earlier point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is called mixed content and is supported in the XmlSerializer.

write your class like this

```
[Serializable]
public class TestClass
{
    [XmlText(typeof(string))]
    [XmlAnyElement]
    public object[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

and put all the elements in the same object array

Comment: Nice! This worked like a charm. Added the ignored text property to your answer as well to make the answer complete.

Comment: A very useful answer to find 4 years later when dealing with legacy XML APIs in the age of JSON

Answer (score 0):

you have to use CDATA - because the tags <> will break the XML-Structure use CDATA or encode your string (maybe b64)

take a look here:

[how-do-you-serialize-a-string-as-cdata-using-xmlserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379888/how-do-you-serialize-a-string-as-cdata-using-xmlserializer)

**EDIT:**

I think your code should look something like this after:

```
  [XmlIgnore]
    public string OtherXML;

    [XmlText]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "OtherXML")]
    XmlCDataSection OtherXMLAsCdata
    {
        get
        {
            var dummy = new XmlDocument();
            return dummy.CreateCDataSection(OtherXML);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                OtherXML = null;
                return;
            }

            OtherXML = value.Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assuming this involves altering the XML before serializing? (adding the cdata element)

Comment: @ruffen take a look at the edit - your InnerText is my OtherXML

Comment: Tried this, but get Empty string in my unit test, does ElementName in XmlElementAttribute correspond to something that has to be present in the XML?

Comment: ElementName defines the NodeName (ElementName) which will be generated by the xmlserializer - by default the ElementName is the PropertyName - but because of the proxy-property "OtherXMLAsCdata" i like to assign the original name of the property with the xml-string (which property is marked with the "XMLIgnore" attribute to prevent the serializer to ser. this proprtyvalue (which would brick the xml)