# XmlSerialization with XmlAnyElement to XmlNode and Order property

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, deserialization

I'm facing an issue with the .Net `XmlSerializer`, basically I need one or more elements with same name to be serialized (and deserialized) dynamically between other elements of fixed schema.

Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <asd>asd</asd>
  <nnn>q</nnn>
  <nnn>w</nnn>
  <nnn>e</nnn>
  <aaa>aaa</aaa>
</A>
```

My real `<nnn>` tag is a little bit more complicated, with dynamic tags inside (not only conditionals), but I'm currently threating this right.
I really need to use the "Order" parameter of `XmlElement` to control some rules.

I can't change the XML layout.

The example serializable class:

```cs
[XmlRoot]
[Serializable]
public class A
{
    [XmlElement("asd", Order=1)]
    public string asd { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string[] qwe { get; set; }

    [XmlAnyElement("nnn", Order=2)]
    public XmlNode[] nnn
    {
        get
        {
            if (qwe == null) return null;

            var xml = new XmlDocument();
            var nodes = new List<XmlNode>(qwe.Length);

            foreach (var q in qwe)
            {
                var nnnTag = xml.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "nnn", null);
                nnnTag.InnerText = q;
                nodes.Add(nnnTag);
            }

            return nodes.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null) return;
            qwe = value.Select(tag => tag.InnerText).ToArray();
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("aaa", Order=3)]
    public string aaa { get; set; }
```

The problem is, when not using the "Order" parameter the serialization goes fine, but with the parameter the elements after the `XmlAnyElement` are understood as part of the array of nodes and so are not deserialized right.

My main program for the example is a Console Application with the following main:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new A
    {
        aaa = "aaa",
        asd = "asd",
        qwe = new[] {"q", "w", "e"}
    };
    var s = Serialize(a);
    var ss = Deserialize<A>(s);
    var s2 = Serialize(ss);

    Console.WriteLine(s);
    Console.WriteLine(s2);

    Console.WriteLine("Equals: {0};", s == s2);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The wrong output is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <asd>asd</asd>
  <nnn>q</nnn>
  <nnn>w</nnn>
  <nnn>e</nnn>
  <aaa>aaa</aaa>
</A>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <asd>asd</asd>
  <nnn>q</nnn>
  <nnn>w</nnn>
  <nnn>e</nnn>
  <nnn>aaa</nnn>
</A>
Equals: False;
```

---

For testing, here is the Serialization/Deserialization snippets I'm using:

```cs
public static string Serialize<T>(T a)
{
    var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
        {
            s.Serialize(sw, a);
            ms.Seek(0, 0);
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(string a)
{
    var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(a);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        return (T) s.Deserialize(ms);
    }
}
```

The full source code:
https://gist.github.com/inventti-gabriel/81054269f2e0a32d7e8d1dd44f30a97f

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does look like a bug to me. Can you give more specifics as to what `nnn` really is? Because you could [change to this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E2b4xp) for the example, but that may not work in your 'real' case. As an aside, note in the example you can simplify your serialize/deserialize methods to use `StringWriter`/`StringReader`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @CharlesMager that this does appear to be a bug in `XmlSerializer`.

That being said, you can work around the bug by introducing an intermediate wrapper class or struct to contain the arbitrary nodes, then modifying your surrogate `nnn` property to return an array of these structs after marking the property with `[XmlElement("nnn", Order = 2)]`:

```
[XmlRoot]
[Serializable]
public class A
{
    [XmlElement("asd", Order = 1)]
    public string asd { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string[] qwe { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("nnn", Order = 2)]
    public XmlNodeWrapper [] nnn
    {
        get
        {
            if (qwe == null)
                return null;

            var xml = new XmlDocument();
            var nodes = new List<XmlNode>(qwe.Length);

            foreach (var q in qwe)
            {
                var nnnTag = xml.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "nnn", null);
                nnnTag.InnerText = q;
                nodes.Add(nnnTag);
            }

            return nodes.Select(n => (XmlNodeWrapper)n.ChildNodes).ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                return;
            qwe = value.Select(tag => tag.InnerText()).ToArray();
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("aaa", Order = 3)]
    public string aaa { get; set; }
}

[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public struct XmlNodeWrapper
{
    public static implicit operator XmlNodeWrapper(XmlNodeList nodes)
    {
        return new XmlNodeWrapper { Nodes = nodes == null ? null : nodes.Cast<XmlNode>().ToArray() };
    }

    public static implicit operator XmlNode[](XmlNodeWrapper wrapper)
    {
        return wrapper.Nodes;
    }

    // Marking the Nodes property with both [XmlAnyElement] and [XmlText] indicates that the node array
    // may contain mixed content (I.e. both XmlElement and XmlText objects).
    // Hat tip: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995609/xmlserializer-node-containing-text-xml-text 
    [XmlAnyElement]
    [XmlText]
    public XmlNode[] Nodes { get; set; }

    public string InnerText()
    {
        if (Nodes == null)
            return null;
        return String.Concat(Nodes.Select(n => n.InnerText));
    }
}
```

Note that the `Nodes` property in `XmlNodeWrapper` is marked with both `[XmlAnyElement]` and `[XmlText]`.  The requirement to do this is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25995609/3744182).

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eoZ1BW).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `XmlArrayAttribute` in place of `XmlAnyElement` as the nodes are array