# Setting text content in object generated by XSD

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, dtd

I have a .dtd file which has been converted to a .xsd file. This file has an element Identity:

```
  <xs:element name="Identity">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##any" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="lastChangedTimestamp" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

This generates the following sample xml, with some text content:

```
<Identity lastChangedTimestamp="lastChangedTimestamp1" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/cXML">text</Identity>
```

I converted the .xsd to a .cs file using xsd.exe:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/cXML")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/cXML", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Identity
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    private System.Xml.XmlNode[] anyField;

    private string lastChangedTimestampField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlNode[] Any
    {
        get
        {
            return this.anyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.anyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string lastChangedTimestamp
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lastChangedTimestampField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.lastChangedTimestampField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

However this does not allow me to set the text content of the identity node:

```
var credential = new Credential()
{
    Identity = new Identity()
    {
        lastChangedTimestamp = "lastChangedTimestamp1",
        //Text = "MyRef" <- would like to set it at this point
    }
};
```

Is there anything I can do to ensure that when I serialize the Identity object I can get my ref into the text content of the node, or is this not supported?

```
<Identity lastChangedTimestamp="lastChangedTimestamp1">
    MyRef
</Identity>
```

Comment: May I assume that you added `public string Text { get; set; }` manually?

Comment: The "Text" is the property I'd assume I would be able to set, but doesn't exist in the auto generated code. I'd like to avoid changing the code generated by the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mixed="true"` in your XSD indicates that the `<Identity>` element can contain [mixed content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#sec-mixed-content):

> An element type has mixed content when elements of that type may contain character data, optionally interspersed with [child](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#dt-parentchild) elements.

Furthermore, the child elements are unconstrained by the XSD.

`xsd.exe` and `XmlSerializer` support mixed content via a combination of the [`[XmlText]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute?view=netframework-4.8) and [`[XmlAnyElement]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attributes.  When both attributes are applied to a member of type `XmlNode[]`, then all mixed content contained in the XML will be bound to that member.

In this case, you will note that `xsd.exe` has created a `public System.Xml.XmlNode[] Any` member with these attributes, so, to add the text "MyRef" to your XML, you need to add an appropriate [`XmlText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltext?view=netframework-4.8) to this array:

```
var identity = new Identity()
{
    lastChangedTimestamp = "lastChangedTimestamp1",
    Any = new XmlNode []
    {
        new XmlDocument().CreateTextNode("MyRef"),
    },
};
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A5qpYh).

Alternatively, you could manually change the `Any` property to be an array of objects as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25997011) to *[XmlSerializer - node containing text + xml + text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25995609)* by [Sruly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72453/sruly)
:

```
[XmlText(typeof(string))]
[XmlAnyElement]
public object[] Any { get; set; }
```

Then you would be able to add the string directly to the array:

```
var identity = new Identity()
{
    lastChangedTimestamp = "lastChangedTimestamp1",
    Any = new object []
    {
        "MyRef",
    },
};
```

(You would still need to allocate `XmlNode` objects for more complex XML.)

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qNsVrS).

Comment: That works great, thanks. I haven't worked much with XML so it's quite counter-intuitive to create a XML Document to store a string but that's the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

In the end I updated the xsd Identity node to add `<xs:extension base="xs:string">`:

```
  <xs:element name="Identity">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="lastChangedTimestamp" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

This created a Text array in my object

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/cXML")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/cXML", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Identity
    {

        private string lastChangedTimestampField;

        private string[] textField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string lastChangedTimestamp
        {
            get
            {
                return this.lastChangedTimestampField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.lastChangedTimestampField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public string[] Text
        {
            get
            {
                return this.textField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.textField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Which I can then use to set my ref:

```
new Credential()
{
    Identity = new Identity()
    {
        Text=new string[]
        {
            "MyRef"
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is the best way but I can use this for now.