# How to generate tags inside another tag in XML c#?

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I have a class file like below :

```
public class property : root
{
   public string languages { get; set; } 
}
```

I am trying to generate `xml` like below :

**Final Output:**

```
<root>
    <property>
    --other properties
        <languages>
            <en>This is English Languages description</en>
            <fr></fr>
        </languages>
    </property>
</root>
```

This is how I am trying to generate the `<languages>` tag :

```
private string GenerateLanguageTag(IList<Languages> languages)
{
    string lang = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in languages)
    {
        lang += "<" + item.IsoLanguageCode + ">" + item.Description + "</" + item.IsoLanguageCode + ">";
    }
    return lang;
}
```

**output:**

```
<root>
    <property>
       --other properties
         <languages>&lt;en&gt;This is English Languages description 
 &lt;/en&gt;&lt;fr&gt;&lt;/fr&gt;</languages>
    </property>
</root>
```

**Code:**

```
root root = GetData(data);
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(root));
using (StringWriter xmlWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, root);
    value = xmlWriter.ToString();
    value = value.Replace(" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"", "");
    value = value.Replace(" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"", "");
    value = value.Replace("utf-16", "ISO-8859-1");            
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        var document = XDocument.Parse(value);
        document.Save(filePath);              
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Tags `"en", "fr"` and many other languages inside `<languages></languages>` are generated dynamically based on the languages we have in the database.

Comment: Use an `[XmlText]` + `[XmlAnyElement]` property as shown in [XmlSerializer - node containing text + xml + text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25997011).  In fact this looks like a duplicate, agree?

Comment: @dbc Sorry I dont think its a duplicate. The link you have provided has "Items" as property name and I am trying to generate a "Languages" tag. Can you give any suggestion how I can use that code to generate the output I want?

Comment: Does the `<languages>` tag repeat, or is there just one?

Comment: @dbc Only 1 <Languages> tag but the languages inside this tag like "en", "fr" and many other languages are dynamic tags generated based on the languages we have in the database

Comment: @Luuk The links are generally for "Html" tags and not specific to the problem I have mentioned

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow: As long as the XML is XML, then it does not matter if tags happen to be HTML tags. Creating HTML tags, in most C# solutions will create the opening and the closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than declaring `languages` as a `string`, declare it as an `XElement` and mark it with [`[XmlAnyElement("languages")]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute).  This informs the serializer that the children of the `languages` property should be inserted as children of their parent `<property>` element.  Thus your data model should look like:

```
public class root
{
    public property property { get; set; }
}

public class property
{
    [XmlAnyElement("languages")]
    public XElement languages { get; set; }
}
```

And you would construct your model as follows:

```
// Your dynamic list of languages & values
var languages = new List<(string IsoLanguageCode, string Description)>
{
    ("en", "This is English Languages description"),
    ("fr", ""),
};

var root = new root()
{
    property = new()
    {
        languages = new XElement("languages", languages.Select(l => new XElement(l.IsoLanguageCode, l.Description))),
    },
};
```

Notes:

- The documentation for [`XmlAnyElementAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute?view=net-6.0) indicates it should be applied to properties of type `XmlElement` or `XmlNode` (or arrays of the same), but in fact it works for properties of type `XElement` as well.  Since LINQ-to-XML is easier to work with than the old `XmlDocument` API, I suggest using it instead.
- In your question you show `property` as a subclass of `root`.  In order to get the nesting you require, it should be a separate class contained by `root`, not a subclass of `root`.
- To eliminate the `xsi` and `xsd` namespaces (without needing to do a string replacement) see *[XmlSerializer: remove unnecessary xsi and xsd namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/760262/3744182)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hEiwo6).

Comment: Omg, you are brilliant. This answer is too good. Thank you, thank you so much. I was really stuck on this. I can't thank you enough. Need suggestion on this particular structure if you can please: <images> <image id= "100"> <url> abc.com </url>
</image> <image id= "100"> <url> abc.com </url> </image> </images>. Any suggestion how I can generate this structure in XML?

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow - The preferred format is [one question per post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275908) so you should probably ask a separate question.  Off the top of my head you could use a `public List<Image> images { get; set; }` property with some appropriate `Image` class.  To control the element and item element names use `[XmlArray("images)]` and `[XmlArrayItem("image")]` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2298726) to [XmlSerializer List Item Element Name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2292480).

Comment: I have posted a question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72218746/incorrect-xml-structure-c-sharp. Can you take a look and guide me if you can

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq :

```
           string header = "<root></root>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(header);

            XElement root = doc.Root;

            root.Add( new XElement("property", new object[] {
                new XElement("languages", new object[] {
                    new XElement("en", "This is English Languages description"),
                    new XElement("fr")
                })
            }));

        }
```

Comment: "en", "fr" is not fixed. We have so many other languages. Tags inside "Languages" are generated dynamically if you see the "GenerateLanguageTag" method. although appreciate your help

Comment: It is an array of new object[].