# CDATA returns &lt;![CDATA instead of <![CDATA[

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, cdata

I have an action in asp.net MVC controller that is returning a serialized object something like this.

```
public ActionResult Test(int ID)
{
    var xmlString= Serialize(object);

    return this.Content(xmlString, "text/xml");

}

public string Serialize<T>(T obj))
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, false); // no BOM in a .NET string
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

            using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
                {
                    ser.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
                }
                return textWriter.ToString(); 
            }
        }
```

One of the elements contains `<![CDATA[` . The problem is that in browser I get `<![CDATA[` , but in document source code it is displayed as `&lt;![CDATA`

To set cdata value I am using new `System.Xml.XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(tempValue).OuterXml;`

What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the (approximate) value of `tempValue`?

Comment: can you post the the actual xml?

Comment: What does your `Serialize` method look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `XmlSerializer` to serialize a string containing the text `<![CDATA[...]]>`.

The `XmlSerializer` will produce XML which can be deserialized to produce exactly the same string.

If it produced:

```
<SomeNode><![CDATA[...]]></SomeNode>
```

then the deserialized value would be:

```
...
```

which doesn't match the original string.

Instead, it will produce:

```
<SomeNode>&lt;![CDATA[...]]&gt;</SomeNode>
```

which will deserialize correctly.

When you're using the `XmlSerializer`, you don't need to worry about encoding your values; the serializer will take care of that for you. Remove the code that uses `CreateCDataSection`, and let the serializer take care of encoding your data properly.

If you need precise control over the generated XML, then don't use the `XmlSerializer`. Use an `XmlWriter`, an `XmlDocument`, or an `XDocument` instead.

Comment: This looks like a solid explanation. But it is explained on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379888/how-do-you-serialize-a-string-as-cdata-using-xmlserializer that my technique should work? I had to make one change, intead of serializing string containg CDATA, I have to serialize System.Xml.XmlCDataSection element.

Comment: @mko: In that thread, the code is returning the result of the `CreateCDataSection` function, which is an `XmlCDataSection` object. Your code is returning its `OuterXml` property, which is a `string`.

Comment: i used that solution and continued with XmlSerializer instad of going with XmlWriter.