# Is it possible to conditionally serialize CDATA?

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I have seen the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379888/how-do-you-serialize-a-string-as-cdata-using-xmlserializer) to get XmlSerializer to output a CDATA section, but is it then possible to conditionally achieve this, based on another value?

The following code demonstrates the result I want:

```
enum LogItemType
{
   Default,
   Xml
}

class LogItem
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public LogItemType Type { get; set; }
   [XmlIgnore]
   public string Value { get; set; }
   public XmlCDataSection ValueString
   {
      if(Type == LogItemType.Xml)
         // return CDATA
      else
         // return string (not CDATA)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the return type of your `ValueString` property to [`XmlCharacterData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlcharacterdata.aspx), which is the base class for [`XmlText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltext.aspx) and [`XmlCDataSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlcdatasection.aspx).  Then return one or the other depending on the state of your `Type` property:

```
public class LogItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public LogItemType Type { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Value")]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public XmlCharacterData ValueString
    {
        get
        {
            if (Value == null)
                return null;
            else if (Type == LogItemType.Xml)
                // return CDATA
                return new XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(Value);
            else
                // return string (not CDATA)
                return new XmlDocument().CreateTextNode(Value);
        }
        set
        {
            Value = value == null ? null : value.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be either:

> ```
> <LogItem>
>     <Name>test</Name>
>     <Type>Default</Type>
>     <Value>this is a test string</Value>
> </LogItem>
> ```

or

> ```
> <LogItem>
>     <Name>test</Name>
>     <Type>Xml</Type>
>     <Value><![CDATA[this is a test string]]></Value>
> </LogItem>
> ```

Alternatively, if you want your `Value` text to be the value of the `LogItem` itself (rather than the value of a nested element) you can do:

```
    [XmlText]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public XmlNode [] ValueString
    {
        get
        {
            if (Value == null)
                return null;
            else if (Type == LogItemType.Xml)
                // return CDATA
                return new XmlNode[] { new XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(Value) };
            else
                // return string (not CDATA)
                return new XmlNode[] { new XmlDocument().CreateTextNode(Value) };
        }
        set
        {
            Value = value == null ? null : string.Concat(value.Select(n => n.Value).ToArray());
        }
    }
```

(Note that an array is returned not a single item.  `XmlSerializer` seems to require this.)

Comment: works like a charm, and your design advice was sound, i made the name and type attributes