# How to deserialize a node in a large document using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xmlserializer

I have a large XML document that I have loaded into an `XmlDocument` and I want to use the `XmlSerializer` class to deserialize selected elements from it into a .NET class generated using xsd.exe.

Here's an MCVE of what I've tried so far; the xsd and generated class are at the end of the post.  As noted in the comments in the code, I am getting an `InvalidOperationException` - `<Cars xmlns:'http://MyNamespace' /> was not expected`:

```
static string XmlContent = @"
    <RootNode xmlns=""http://MyNamespace"">
        <Cars>
        <Car make=""Volkswagen"" />
        <Car make=""Ford"" />
        <Car make=""Opel"" />
        </Cars>
    </RootNode>";

static void TestMcve()
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(XmlContent);
    var nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nsMgr.AddNamespace("myns", "http://MyNamespace");
    var rootSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootNode));
    var root = (RootNode) rootSerializer.Deserialize(new XmlNodeReader(doc));
    Console.WriteLine(root.Cars[0].make); // Works fine so far

    var node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("myns:Cars", nsMgr);
    Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
    var carSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car));
    using (var reader = new XmlNodeReader(node))
    {
        // What I want is a list of Car instances deserialized from
        // the Car child elements of the Cars element.
        // The following line throws an InvalidOperationException
        // "<Cars xmlns:'http://MyNamespace' /> was not expected"
        // If I change SelectSingleNode above to select "myns:Cars/myns:Car"
        // I get "<Car xmlns:'http://MyNamespace' /> was not expected"
        var result = carSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

I also want to subsequently update my `Car` class instance, and insert it back into the document using the `XmlSerializer`, which is the subject of a follow-up question [How to insert a node in a large document using XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48659674/13087)
.

The xsd and generated classes follow:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://MyNamespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           targetNamespace="http://MyNamespace" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           version="3.9.0.8">
  <xs:complexType name="Cars">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Car" type="Car" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Car">
    <xs:attribute name="make" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="RootNode">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Cars" type="Cars" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="RootNode" type="RootNode" />
</xs:schema>
```

Code generated by xsd.exe:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://MyNamespace")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://MyNamespace", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class RootNode {

    private Car[] carsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute(IsNullable=false)]
    public Car[] Cars {
        get {
            return this.carsField;
        }
        set {
            this.carsField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://MyNamespace")]
public partial class Car {

    private string makeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string make {
        get {
            return this.makeField;
        }
        set {
            this.makeField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. The `var node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("myns:Cars", nsMgr);` is positioned at the `<Cars>` element -- the container element for the repeating sequence of `<Car>` nodes -- but your `XmlSerializer` is constructed to deserialize a single root element named `<Car>`.  Trying to deserialize a sequence of cars with a serializer constructed to deserialize a single car will not work.
2. For some reason `xsd.exe` generated a definition for your `Car` type without an [`XmlRoot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx) attribute:

   ```
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://MyNamespace")]
   // Not included!
   //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://MyNamespace")]
   public partial class Car
   {
   }
   ```

   Thus if you attempt to serialize or deserialize a single instance of a `Car` *as the root XML element of an XML document* then `XmlSerializer` will expect that root element to not be in any namespace.  Each `<Car>` node in your large document is in the `"http://MyNamespace"` default namespace, so attempting to deserialize each one individually also will not work.

   You could manually add the missing `[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://MyNamespace")]` attribute to `Car`, but having to do this can be a nuisance if the XSD files are subsequently modified and the c# types need to be regenerated.

To avoid both issues, you can use [`XmlNode.SelectNodes(String, XmlNamespaceManager)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9.aspx) to select every `<Car>` nodes inside the `<Cars>` element, then deserialize each one by [constructing an `XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1wczcys.aspx) with an override `XmlRootAttribute` with the element name and namespace of the node being deserialized.  First, define the following extension methods:

```
public static partial class XmlNodeExtensions
{
    public static List<T> DeserializeList<T>(this XmlNodeList nodes)
    {
        return nodes.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(n => n.Deserialize<T>()).ToList();
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(this XmlNode node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return default(T);
        var serializer = XmlSerializerFactory.Create(typeof(T), node.LocalName, node.NamespaceURI);
        using (var reader = new XmlNodeReader(node))
        {
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}

public static class XmlSerializerFactory
{
    // To avoid a memory leak the serializer must be cached.
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897145/memory-leak-using-streamreader-and-xmlserializer
    // This factory taken from 
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128757/wrap-properties-with-cdata-section-xml-serialization-c-sharp/34138648#34138648

    readonly static Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string, string>, XmlSerializer> cache;
    readonly static object padlock;

    static XmlSerializerFactory()
    {
        padlock = new object();
        cache = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string, string>, XmlSerializer>();
    }

    public static XmlSerializer Create(Type serializedType, string rootName, string rootNamespace)
    {
        if (serializedType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (rootName == null && rootNamespace == null)
            return new XmlSerializer(serializedType);
        lock (padlock)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer;
            var key = Tuple.Create(serializedType, rootName, rootNamespace);
            if (!cache.TryGetValue(key, out serializer))
                cache[key] = serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializedType, new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = rootName, Namespace = rootNamespace });
            return serializer;
        }
    }
}
```

Then deserialize as follows:

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("myns:Cars/myns:Car", nsMgr);
var cars = nodes.DeserializeList<Car>();
```

Node that a serializer constructed with an override root element name or namespace must be cached to avoid a memory leak as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23897411/3744182) by [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell).

Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HNO552).