# How to insert a node in a large document using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xmlserializer

I have a large XML document and I want to use the `XmlSerializer` class to insert new elements whose content comes from a .NET class instance generated using xsd.exe.

This is a follow-up to the question [How to deserialize a node in a large document using XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48652270/13087), and uses the same xsd and generated classes that are described in that question.

Let's say that in my sample XML I want to exchange my Ford car for a BMW.  I've tried the following code:

```
static string XmlContent = @"
    <RootNode xmlns=""http://MyNamespace"">
        <Cars>
        <Car make=""Volkswagen"" />
        <Car make=""Ford"" />
        <Car make=""Opel"" />
        </Cars>
    </RootNode>";

private static void TestWriteMcve()
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(XmlContent);
    var nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nsMgr.AddNamespace("myns", "http://MyNamespace");

    var node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("myns:Cars/myns:Car[@make='Ford']", nsMgr);
    var parent = node.ParentNode;
    var carSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car));

    using (var writer = node.CreateNavigator().InsertAfter())
    {
        // WriteWhitespace needed to avoid error "WriteStartDocument cannot
        // be called on writers created with ConformanceLevel.Fragment."
        writer.WriteWhitespace("");
        var newCar = new Car { make = "BMW" };
        carSerializer.Serialize(writer, newCar);
    }
    parent.RemoveChild(node);
    Console.WriteLine(parent.OuterXml);
}
```

The result I get is close to what I want:

```
<Cars xmlns="http://MyNamespace">
  <Car make="Volkswagen" />
  <Car xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" make="BMW" xmlns="" />
  <Car make="Opel" />
</Cars>
```

except for all those unwanted `xmlns:...` attributes on the element that was added.  Where did they come from and how can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in *[Omitting all xsi and xsd namespaces when serializing an object in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/625927/3744182)*, `XmlSerializer` will always helpfully add the `xsi` and `xsd` namespaces when serializing.  If you don't want that, you need to call an overload of `Serialize` where the required initial namespaces can be specified, e.g. [`XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter, Object, XmlSerializerNamespaces)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z5zfc6h.aspx).  The following extension method does the trick:

```
public static class XmlNodeExtensions
{
    public static XmlNode ReplaceWithSerializationOf<T>(this XmlNode node, T replacement)
    {
        if (node == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var parent = node.ParentNode;
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(replacement == null ? typeof(T) : replacement.GetType());

        using (var writer = node.CreateNavigator().InsertAfter())
        {
            // WriteWhitespace needed to avoid error "WriteStartDocument cannot
            // be called on writers created with ConformanceLevel.Fragment."
            writer.WriteWhitespace("");

            // Set up an appropriate initial namespace.
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add(node.GetNamespaceOfPrefix(node.NamespaceURI), node.NamespaceURI);

            // Serialize
            serializer.Serialize(writer, replacement, ns);
        }

        var nextNode = node.NextSibling;
        parent.RemoveChild(node);
        return nextNode;
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
var newCar = new Car { make = "BMW" };
var node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("myns:Cars/myns:Car[@make='Ford']", nsMgr);
node = node.ReplaceWithSerializationOf(newCar);
var parent = node.ParentNode;
```

Afterwards, the XML generated for `doc` will be:

```
<RootNode xmlns="http://MyNamespace">
  <Cars>
    <Car make="Volkswagen" />
    <Car make="BMW" />
    <Car make="Opel" />
  </Cars>
</RootNode>
```

Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/17fGcN).

Comment: That's great thanks.  I'd assumed that the attributes added to the auto-generated classes by xsd.exe would be enough.

Comment: @Joe - the XML generated using the auto-generated classes is perfectly valid and well-formed.  It's just less compact that you would like.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, as is your answer to the linked related question.  I particularly appreciate that you went to the trouble of creating a working .Net fiddle.