# XmlSerialize Class to CDATA

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xmlserializer

Due to one of the interfaces we are writing for, we have to add a CDATA tag for a list of classes.

```xml
    <modules>
        <![CDATA[<module>
            <title></title>
            <code></code>
            <level></level>
            <year></year>
            <summary></summary>
        </module>
          <module>
            <title></title>
            <code></code>
            <level></level>
            <year></year>
            <summary></summary>
        </module>]]>
    </modules>
```

I'm unsure how to achieve this. I have found questions around individual strings, but not so much around an entire class.
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Would it work in a two-step process where you serialize the list of "modules" to XML and then add the result *as string* to the `<modules>` node?

Comment: Does [Wrap properties with CData Section - XML Serialization C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34128757/3744182) answer your question?  The answer shows how to use nested serialization to embed serialized XML in a CDATA section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*One of the ways* to get the output you are expecting is to `separate` the creation of the `module` data and generating the `CDATA` part. For example:

**To create the `module` data -**

1. Create a class to hold module details as below -

   ```
   public class Module
   {
       public string title { get; set; }
       public string code { get; set; }
       public string level { get; set; }
       public string summary { get; set; }
    }
   ```
2. Create a method to fetch these datails -

   ```
    public static string CreateXMLString()
      {
       List<Module> modules = new List<Module>();
       modules = new List<Module>() { new Module() { code = "test", 
       summary="Test3", title="Test", level = "tests1" },
                                          new Module() { code = "test3", 
       summary="Test3", title="Test3", level = "tests3" } };

           // Create XML to return the string in the format of 
           // <module code="test">
           //  < level > tests1 </ level >
           //  < summary > Test3 </ summary >
           //  < title > Test </ title >
           //</ module >< module code = "test3" >   
           //     < level > tests3 </ level >   
           //     < summary > Test3 </ summary >   
           //     < title > Test3 </ title >
           //   </ module >

         var modulesXml = 
             from mod in modules
             select new XElement("module",
           new XAttribute("code", mod.code),
           new XElement("level", mod.level),
           new XElement("summary", mod.summary),
           new XElement("title", mod.title)
          );

         return String.Concat(modulesXml);
       }
   ```

**To get the `CDATA` you can use the below steps -**

3. Create a class `Modules`and refer the documentation for usages of  [`CreateCDataSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.createcdatasection?view=netcore-3.1) and for [`similar threads here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379888/how-do-you-serialize-a-string-as-cdata-using-xmlserializer/1380050) for the details

   ```
   [XmlType("")]
   public class Modules
   {
    public Modules() { }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("modules")]
    public System.Xml.XmlCDataSection MyStringCDATA
    {
        get
        {
           return new System.Xml.XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(Message);
        }
        set
        {
           Message = value.Value;
        }
    }
   }
   ```

**To test the output assign the string generated in step 2 during serialization you can refer the sample code below**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   Modules mc = new Modules();
   mc.Message = CreateXMLString();//Assign your data created in step 2
   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Modules));
   XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
   ns.Add("", "");
       
   StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

    //Remove unnecessary namespaces
   serializer.Serialize(writer, mc,ns);
   var test = XDocument.Parse(writer.ToString());            
            
   var data = test.Root.Elements();              
            
   Console.WriteLine(data.FirstOrDefault().Value);

 }
```

**Output -**

```
<modules>
<![CDATA[<module>
  <code>test</code>
  <level>tests1</level>
  <summary>Test3</summary>
  <title>Test</title>
</module><module>
  <code>test3</code>
  <level>tests3</level>
  <summary>Test3</summary>
  <title>Test3</title>
</module>]]>
</modules>
```