# Error assigning value to a list of XCData before xml serialization in C#

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, cdata

I have a class with an XMLElement of type Message:

```
public class TimeBlock
{
  public TimeBlock()
  {
    info = new Message();
  }
  [XmlElement("ReceivedInfo")]
  public Message info { get; set; }
}
```

which is a self-defined class containing XMLElement of type List.

```
    [XmlElement("ReformedLine")]
    public List<XCData> reformedBody { get; set; }
```

where "line" is a string. In the main method I have:

```
    XCData reformedLine = new XCData(line);
    timeBlock.info.reformedBody.Add(reformedLine);
```

But after running it throws the exception of:

```
System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
```

How can I solve this? Generally, how should I wrap a part of Data I want to serialize into CDATA (before forming the XML document and having access to the nodes)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you serialize a string as CDATA using XmlSerializer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379888/how-do-you-serialize-a-string-as-cdata-using-xmlserializer)

Comment: No it's not. When I have a single variable of type string the link you mentioned works. But when I have a list defined, it doesn't work anymore. @Sinatr