# Generate xml in c# with CDATA wrapped by another CDATA

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, cdata, solution

I Have a xml model like that:

```
<tag1>
...
    <![CDATA[
        <tag2/>
        ...
        <![CDATA[
            <tag3/>
            ...
        ]]]]><![CDATA[>
    ]]>
</tag1>
```

I try to use c# XmlSerializer but don't find a way to generate one CDATA wrapped by another. I try create inner CDATA and that add result to model and serialize that model, but can't do that, cause get InvalidOperationException, case CDATA block has ']]>'. As field in model for CDATA block i use XMLCDataSection.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you serialize a string as CDATA using XmlSerializer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379888/how-do-you-serialize-a-string-as-cdata-using-xmlserializer)

Comment: A have never seen garbage like that before.  You would need a custom parser.  I could write a recursive parser very easily, but would need a better sample of the file.