# Deserialize XML into C# Model with CDATA

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, cdata, xml-deserialization

I'm Deserializing following XML to a C# Object

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Message>
  <Request>
    <FromInfo>
      <Provider>
        <ProviderName><![CDATA[Name]]></ProviderName>
      </Provider>
    </FromInfo>
    <ToInfo>
      <Provider>
        <ProviderID><![CDATA[123]]></ProviderID>
        <ID><![CDATA[1]]></ID>
      </Provider>
    </ToInfo>
  </Request>
  <RS>
    <Add>
      <AccountInfoRecord>
        <UserInfo>
          <FirstName><![CDATA[Some]]></FirstName>
          <LastName><![CDATA[Name]]></LastName>
          <DayPhone><![CDATA[0123456]]></DayPhone>
          <Email><![CDATA[SampleEmail]]></Email>
          <UserAddress>
            <Address1><![CDATA[Address]]></Address1>
            <Address2><![CDATA[Something]]></Address2>
            <City><![CDATA[Oslo]]></City>
            <State />
            <PostalCode><![CDATA[1330]]></PostalCode>
            <Country><![CDATA[some]]></Country>
          </UserAddress>
        </UserInfo>
        <YourUserKey />
      </AccountInfoRecord>
    </Add>
  </RS>
</Message>
```

I get an Error in `<State />`

But not in `<YourUserKey />` and `<State></State>`

Following is the Error
`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlElement' to type 'System.Xml.XmlCDataSection'.`

And this is the Model Class

```
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "State")]
        public XmlCDataSection StateCData
        {
            get
            {
                return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(State)
                    ? new XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(State) : null;
            }
            set
            {
                State = value?.Value;
            }
        }
```

I went through several threads as well, but could not find a specific answer.

[How do you serialize a string as CDATA using XmlSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379888/how-do-you-serialize-a-string-as-cdata-using-xmlserializer/43211105#43211105)

Comment: Why is there a requirement to use CDATA?

Comment: does `public string State {get;set;}` not work? including for the CDATA ones? i.e. `public string PostalCode {get;set;}`? it is pretty unusual to tie things to `XmlCDataSection`

Comment: CData is a requirement as the data may contain other languages as well as symbols